# has_many :through association confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, model-associations

I'm new to ruby on rails and i'm stuck with associations.

I want to develop a web app where a member can create a contact. A contact can have one or more categories (Baker / Actor / Developer / anything).

From that, I know I need at least three models : member, contact and categories.
I also created the model categories_contacts.

Here are my models associations :

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :member
   has_many :categories_contacts
   has_many :categories, :through => :categories_contacts
end



   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :categories_contacts
      has_many :contacts, :through => :categories_contacts
   end




 class CategoriesContacts < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :contact
     belongs_to :category
  end
```

Is it ok ?

And then, I would like to get all the contacts by categories.

Example :

Categories : actors, directors

Contact 1 : name(John), categories(actors, directors)

Contact 2 : name(Zack), category(actors)

Contact 3 : name(Luck), category(directors)

If I sort by actors, I would get

Categorie : Actors =>

Contact 1 : name(John)

Contact 2 : name(Zack)

But I don't know how to get all my contacts in my controller.
I tried stuff but nothing works.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems fine.

Try that:

```
Contact.joins(:categories).where("categories.id in ?", params[:category_ids]).all
```

If you want to sort:

```
Contact.joins(:categories).where("categories.id in ?", params[:category_ids]).order("contacts.name ASC")
```

Comment: Kind of the same error as the precedent answer : uninitialized constant Contact::CategoriesContact

Comment: Try to understand why it's searching for CategoriesContact in a Contact module...